# Outputting meta data for custom post type does not work in frontend template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I have created a custom post type in my WordPress functions.php file called 'events' and added a custom metabox with a field to add an event date which works fine and lets me add the information as needed.

The issue is that in my index.php template file when I try to output any of the posts data for example the ID it does not work but if I view for instance my homepage which also uses the index.php file as a template general field data outputs fine for instance:

```
echo $post->ID; (This outputs correctly when viewed on the homepage but is empty on the custom post page);
echo get_the_ID() (Same result as above)
```

Or if I add a loop to show all data on the page:

```
$myvals = get_post_meta($post->ID);

foreach($myvals as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $key . ' : value ' . $val[0] . '<br/>';
}
```

This works fine on other pages but throws a error on my custom post page...

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\lamb\wp-content\themes\lamb\index.php on line 15

Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<main id="site-content">

    <p>test test</p>


<?php 


$myvals = get_post_meta($post->ID);

foreach($myvals as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $key . ' : value ' . $val[0] . '<br/>';
}
?>

</main><!-- #site-content -->


<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Below is the functions.php which adds the custom post type:

```
//Add events post type
function add_events_post_type() {
    register_post_type('events',
        array(
            'labels'      => array(
                'name'          => __('Events at the lamb', 'textdomain'),
                'singular_name' => __('Event', 'textdomain'),
            ),
                'public'      => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'add_events_post_type');


//Add event details metabox to events
function wporg_event_details() {
    add_meta_box(
        'wporg_event_options', // Unique ID
        'Event details', // Box title
        'wporg_event_details_html', // Content callback, must be of type callable
        'events' // Post type
    );
}

//Add field for event
function wporg_event_details_html( $post ) {
    $event_date_text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event-date', true );
    ?>
    <label for="event-date">Event date</label>
    <input type="text" name="event-date" id="event-date" class="date" readonly placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" value="<?php echo $event_date_text;?>">
    <?php
}


//Save post data
function wporg_save_event_details( $post_id ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'event-date', $_POST ) ) {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            'event-date',
            $_POST['event-date']
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wporg_save_event_details' );
```

Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

Comment: `$post` probably doesn't exist in that context then. Have you tried to "import" it using `global $post;` at the start of your template file?

Comment: @CBroe yes I tried that but it didn't make any difference

Comment: Then try if you can get it via https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/